# IPhone: Why is Xcode ignoring my code signing request?

Tags: iphone, xcode

Xcode keeps picking my developer provision. This is even if I pick "Don't Code Sign" or even if I pick my distribution profile.

I tried to set this in both the project properties and also into the target->info window. But it seems to only want to use my developer provision. Where else can I look, what can I delete, etc?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go into your .xcodeproj directory and open project.pbxproj with a text editor.  Likely as not you'll find one of the signing settings isn't what you expect.  I've seen XCode display settings in the GUI that don't agree with what is in the .pbxproj file.

Of course, make sure you're able to restore your old project.pbxproj file just in case you make a change that breaks it.

Comment: You are now officially my hero